# Network icon on unity panel gone in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: unity, wireless, 15.10, indicator, panel

I recently noticed that the Network / Wifi icon is missing in Ubuntu 15.10 unity panel. The network is working perfect, the only problem is that I cant see if I'm connected or not, and if I want to change networks I have to do it through the system settings. (unnecessary long procedure)

I've tried all the troubleshooting steps I found on Google, but nothing worked. Then I tried reinstalling Ubuntu which initially solved the problem, but after doing some updates it disappeared again.

Anyone with the same problem? 
Anyone with a solution?

note:
if i post nm-applet in terminal i get this feedback:

```
**nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
(nm-applet:15724): nm-applet-WARNING **: Could not find ShellVersion property on org.gnome.Shell after 5 tries
(nm-applet:15724): nm-applet-WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (32) An agent with this ID is already registered for this user.
^Cnm-applet-Message: PID 0 (we are 15724) sent signal 2, shutting down...
(nm-applet:15724): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 220 was not found when attempting to remove it**
```

Extra info-> my network adapter

```
network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 20:10:7a:39:71:70
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.248 (r487574) ip=192.168.0.212 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:d4400000-d4403fff
```

Comment: EDIT: I just noticed that the problem might be in the panel. There are other icons missing (like radiotray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

Problem seems to be solved due to updates or something 
(i woke up this morning ans all the icons are back)